# How to fix ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in relational tables

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I am using following query:

```
SELECT MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID AS ID,
  description,
  status,
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) as count
  FROM monitor_alert_ins_msrmnt
  WHERE monitor_alert_instance_id IN (SELECT monitor_alert_instance_id
                                      FROM monitor_alert_instance
                                      WHERE co_mod_asset_id =1234
                                      ) 
                                      GROUP BY monitor_alert_instance_id 
                                      ORDER BY monitor_alert_instance_id
  ) AS COUNT
FROM monitor_alert_instance
WHERE co_mod_asset_id = 1234
```

The inner query returns correct result. I am trying to combining two queries at a time and want to get the result as following:

```
> ID    DESCRIPTION     STATUS  COUNT 
> 101        aaa          A       1
> 102        bbb          B       3
```

But it is showing missing right parenthesis error. Any help please.

Comment: Why you need order by in inner query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any missing parentheses, but I do see a danger with the query.  You are doing a `group by` in the query which could produce more than one row.  That will generate an error, because a scalar subquery should return only one value.

```
SELECT MONITOR_ALERT_INSTANCE_ID AS ID, description, status,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM monitor_alert_ins_msrmnt maim
        WHERE monitor_alert_instance_id IN (SELECT monitor_alert_instance_id
                                            FROM monitor_alert_instance
                                            WHERE co_mod_asset_id =1234
                                           ) and
             maim.monitor_alert_instance_id = mai.monitor_alert_instance_id
       ) AS "COUNT"
FROM monitor_alert_instance mai
WHERE co_mod_asset_id = 1234;
```

This makes the subquery a correlated subquery, removing the `group by` and `order by` because these are not needed.